# Opera throws DOMException from selectNodeContents

Tags: javascript, dom, opera

I'm making a portable documentation with pure html and javascript that should be cross-browser compatible. I am placing the search/highlighter box and results page in separate frames. It all works fine in ie, ff and chrome (with the disable-web-security parameter) but throws error in Opera. I don't have a clue why is this and how could this be fixed.

Any help is appreciated.

The function from where Opera throws the exception:

```
function selectElementContents(el) {
    if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
} else if (document.selection && document.body.createTextRange) {
    var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    textRange.moveToElementText(el);
    textRange.select();
}
}
```

Opera's error console:

```
Uncaught exception: DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR
Error thrown at line 56, column 8 in selectElementContents(el) in xy.js:
range.selectNodeContents(el);
```

Comment: you are violating cross-domain policy. But without code its hard to say where. Please, add jsfiddle, if you can.

Comment: I will try to add a jsfiddle... Until that is done, is there a way to disable this security option in opera? There is for chrome with a parameter... on firefox it works, on ie it needs a mark of the web stupidity that blocks pdf/xls links to open up...

Comment: I can't do jsfiddle as it has frames... maybe if the highlighter function wouldn't be an interframe function it would work. The script is called from the left frame and words highlighted on in the container frame.

Comment: ok, i understand the idea. Check this solution out: http://jsfiddle.net/zLtXu/  - if you are smart and not as tired as me atm, you will understand, how it works. IF not, comment, and i will give you further explanations tomorrow. (And yeah, there is _horrible_ code in that fiddle, its not crossbrowser and so on. Merely a proof of concept.) The trouble was because you are using one window to get selection, and other window to get elements from, and when they don't match - Opera throws exception.

Comment: Thanks! I think I see what you mean. But how is this, I viewed it with firefox and got the alert box, but with opera it just selects the ""This will get selected." That would be great if I could make my highlighter to work with function that is called only in Opera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the range in the document where you are going to use it. I think you've solved this already based on the jsfiddle demo, but for example the line

```
var range = document.createRange();
```

should be

```
 var range = el.ownerDocument.createRange();
```